# View a project on GitHub in action, to see its functionality

Tags: github

I forked several projects on GitHub based on keywords that reflect their functionality. However, I need a visual version of a working app (as opposed to its code) so I know if it is what I want to contribute to replicate later.

How do I do that?

Comment: What is "visual version of a working app"? Do you want there to be live examples of the various projects?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to running the application to see its GUI (assuming that the application has a GUI), you need to clone the project onto your local hard disk. There are instructions on GitHub Help on [Cloning a Repository](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/).

If you have Git installed on your computer, you simply open up a Terminal, `cd` to the correct location on your computer and type in:

```
git clone git@github.com:<YOUR_USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY_NAME>.git
```

After that you will probably need to perform some sort of setup procedure such as compilation. These steps are normally documented in a project's README, CONTRIBUTING, or INSTALL file.